# Ajax query wont work

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following code :

```
var _07votes = $("#07votes");
$(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
                $.ajax({
                        url: "http://services.runescape.com/m=poll/retro_ajax_result?callback=?",
                        method: "GET",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        timeout: 10000;
                }).done(function(data){
                        if (data.votes > 0) {
                                _07votes.text("" + data.votes);
                        }
                });
        }, 3000);
});
```

I can't get this Ajax code to work, it's like it won't query. Would anyone know why?

Comment: Do you get any error? Check the error console.

Comment: I don't think you need to specify the `callback=?` at the end of the URL - jQuery takes care of that for you and pipes the success result to the `.done` method automatically. I think...

Comment: Also, why are you setting the `contentType` as "application/json" for `jsonp`? You're not sending any data...

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the reference to the element where you put the result before it exists. Move it inside the `ready` event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var _07votes = $("#07votes");
  ...
```

#### Edit:

Also, remove the semicolon after the timeout value:

```
timeout: 10000
```

Comment: I don't follow. It'll still be in scope, just in the global scope.

Comment: @Claudiu But getting the element with an `id` of "07votes" _may not_ be available/ready **before** the DOM ready event. If you put it inside of `$(document).ready`, it (guarantees) that the elements on the page are ready for manipulation, and you will definitely be able to access it in the `done` method

Comment: ohh i see it now, yep, my bad. I thought the `$()` call was creating the element, not looking it up.

Comment: That still isn't working for some weird reason. I don't mean to bother you but can anyone take a look at the entire code and tell me the issue? pastebin.com/44nfvNqn

Comment: @user2058739: Please don't neglect to observe errors in your console. You'll have at least one syntax error. Also, you're requesting JSONP, but the delivered response seems to be JSON.

Comment: @the system: I'm not getting any errors in the console, I should've said that before, sorry. I'll try changing that and see if that works, thanks!

Comment: @user2058739: Removing the semicolon after the timeout value, it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/bRPdt/

Comment: @user2058739: Then you're looking at the wrong console. Make sure you're looking at the developer console that reports JavaScript errors. Or make sure you don't have JS errors filtered out.

Comment: @user2058739 Are you able to look at a "Network" tab in your console? Make sure the request is actually being sent out, and an HTTP 200 response is coming back (even look at its contents to see if it's filled with what you expect)

Answer (score -2):

In addition to Guffa's answer, you must first parse the JSON-response (when you succeed to retrieve it).

You can do this using the [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)-method.

Comment: setting the `dataType` does this for you.

Comment: @Zar And if you don't set the `dataType`, jQuery attempts to parse the response based on the HTTP header for "Content-Type" in the response - so that depends on the server setting it or not

Comment: @Ian Good to know, safe to say that you learn something new everyday. Thanks!

Comment: @Zar No problem! Yeah, you can read about it and maybe understand it a little better than I explained: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings